# Locked out of Windows 10 for 30 days due to Linux Dual Boot Install

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, grub, dualboot

I installed Ubuntu for dual boot on my Windows 10 PC.

However, as many people mentioned in similar questions, I have a Bitlocker recovery key prompt when I try to load Windows from the grub menu.

1) I do not have the recovery key and I cannot access it since my Microsoft account was not correctly configured to my current phone and I do not receive the SMS codes. I changed this, but I have to wait 30 DAYS in order to have access again.

2) I cannot access Windows from the BIOS menu as it just restarts the computer to the grub menu.

I have a backup I made of Windows right before this installation.

What's the best way to proceed to regain access to my Windows account and potentially correctly reinstall Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the best way to proceed to regain access to my Windows account and potentially correctly reinstall Linux?

Due to the current configuration of your system, the only way to regain access to your Windows installation, is with the recovery key.  Due to the configuration change I suspect, even if you were to restore your backup, the prompt for the recovery key would continue.

By using BitLocker you have encrypted the entire volume and there is no way to access your data without the recovery key.  When you enabled BitLocker intentionally on the system you were prompted several times to backup the recovery key.

**If you recovery key was to uploaded to your Microsoft Account then there isn't a solution to your problem.**

Comment: I don't believe I configured bitlocker. I never received these prompts before.

Comment: It sounds like you had Device Encryption enabled in that case.  BitLocker cannot be enabled without at least being prompted once to backup your recovery key.

Comment: I didn't have this issue before installing Linux in dual boot...Why can't I just "undo" my actions?

Comment: @StefanN - It's a security measure.  You might be able to get around the security feature, if and only if, you restore a complete image of the HDD.  However, if Windows still detects a configuration change, you will still be prompted for the recovery key.